# User upload fields

Tags: plugins

Need help with a function that will do this things

1. User can make an account from frontend
2. Can upload some documents in his account
3. Can edit or replace the documents uploaded already

I was searching for plugin or function that will be able to do this but no luck :(

Comment: What all have you tried till now?

Comment: Ultimate member, caldera form, and almost all plugins from wordpress repository. Now Ițm, trying to use extra fields for user, but still the same thing..

Comment: I think you'll have to write custom functions to achieve these.

Comment: any reference you can gave me?

Comment: for point 1, is it simple registration or you want user to give permission to create new fields? For 2 and 3 you can use user_meta fields to save the reference of uploaded doc and add option to edit/delete them.